# Sharing git file conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, merge, rebase, git-rebase

I've gotten myself into a pickle here with our git project. We've been forced (by circumstance) to split the team into two fronts, one side working on a massive upgrade/overhaul task, the other working on features/bugfixes on top of our last release (which was where the branches split off)

Trouble is, that was six months ago. Now, the features team is done, and I'm faced with the unenviable task of merging these two branches, which contain six months work each, into a single, cohesive state.

Needless to say, there were conflicts... lots of them. Almost 400 to be specific. I was able to minimize the chaos by rebasing instead of simply merging, which already helped a lot, especially where modified files from one branch had been moved to other locations in the other branch. There were quite a lot of those.

Now, while the conflicts themselves aren't particularly difficult to solve in most cases, I can't shake the feeling that this shouldn't be a job for any single dev to take on alone.

Git doesn't seem to be its usual helpful self in this area. Because the ideal git workflow expects conflicts to be kept small and dealt with promptly, there doesn't seem to be a way to *share* merging efforts with the rest of the team.

That would have been ideal. To be able to commit files **without** stripping them of their conflicted states. That way, other devs could check out the ongoing merge branch, and help clear up conflicts from their sides, each dev taking on the files that they've worked on and know best.

That doesn't seem to be possible though... Not as far as I was able to find.

Hence this question. Does anyone know if there is a way to commit conflicted files without staging them (thereby marking them as technically resolved, making them difficult to find later)?

I would love to be able to check out a conflicted branch, see the conflicts there, and help out whenever someone runs into trouble, or in this case, to enlist the help of the team of developers who are now just sat waiting for me to finish solving conflicts the best I can, without a lot of contextual information to go on, so they can later move in and rely on the conflict notes from the merge commit message only to try and figure out where their work might have been overwritten.

As always, many thanks in advance for any ideas/thoughts/brainfarts. Anything helps, if at least to vent the frustration of having to work through 400 file conflicts.

Cheers

---

Well, a follow up at least, I was able to work through *all* conflicts on my own here... it took a fair few hours, but it got done.

Then, after the (very much expected) barrage of compile errors I got, I went over all the code files in the project with a diff tool (comparing against another repo checked out to one of the source branches), and corrected any problems where the rebase operation (and subsequent conflict solving marathon) failed.

That went well into the wee hours, but I managed to end the day with a project that compiled :)

Today I'm working on revising the project asset files and their linkages in the project. This is simpler, and the game is looking like its normal self again, so the level of despair goes down proportionally.

Still, if anyone knows of a way to share a big conflict operation (some means of committing without staging away the conflicted states, or perhaps a way to retrieve technically resolved but still conflicted files up again), that would be most welcome information, should this (shudders) ever happen again in the future, to anyone.

Thanks for the responses!

Cheers

Comment: Good luck my friend. I am surprise with such a beautiful tool some one is still following anti pattern. Git manta "Small change frequent merge/rebase"

Comment: This wasn't by choice, trust me... We were forced into a situation where either we diverged, or half the team would be paralyzed. True, there could have been more frequent merges to keep things sane, but no one expected the overhaul team to hit as many delays as we did... and hindsight is a wonderful thing isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely commit files that have been marked up by git as being in conflict. I'd recommend that you create a new branch and merge your two current branches into that one. That way, people can continue working on the current branches while you and your teammates resolve the problem on the third `merge` branch.

You're right to note that this is a problem for more than one person. If it's a big enough project, you'll often have teams that are involved with changing certain parts of the code, so those people would be responsible for resolving merge conflicts in those parts of the code on the `merge` branch.

Once everything has been merged, you can simply switch development over to the `merge` branch or merge it back into your `master` branch.

Comment: Aye, I was able to `git commit -a` and push the conflicted files, but then, they wouldn't show as conflicted on a `status` call, (nor on the smartgit client, which everyone on the team uses).

I was able to use rebase instead of merge to minimize the problems of files being treated as additions/removals when in one branch they had been moved, and modified on the other.

Comment: @HarvesteR I don't understand the second part of your statement. As for the first, once you add and commit a file, git will no longer mark it as conflicted. That's normal. That's why it should be in a separate branch. It's up to you to realize when the files have been fixed to then `merge`/`rebase` them back to `master`